# Embedded C++ : to use STL or not?

Tags: c++, stl, embedded

I have always been an embedded software engineer, but usually at Layer 3 or 2 of the OSI stack. I am not really a hardware guy. I have generally always done telecoms products, usually hand/cell-phones, which generally means something like an ARM 7 processor.

Now I find myself in a more generic embedded world, in a small start-up, where I might move to "not so powerful" processors (there's the subjective bit) - I cannot predict which.

I have read quite a bit about debate about using STL in C++ in embedded systems and there is no clear cut answer. There are some small worries about portability, and a few about code size or run-time, but I have two major concerns:
  1 - exception handling; I am still not sure whether to use it (see [Embedded C++ : to use exceptions or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226227/embeeded-c-to-use-exceptions-or-not))
  2 - I strongly dislike dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems, because of the problems it can introduce. I generally have a buffer pool which is statically allocated at compile time and which serves up only fixed size buffers (if no buffers, system reset). The STL, of course, does a lot of dynamic allocation.

Now I have to make the decision whether to use or forego the STL - for the whole company, for ever (it's going into some very core s/w).

Which way do I jump? Super-safe & lose much of what constitutes C++ (imo, it's more than just the language definition) and maybe run into problems later or have to add lots of exception handling & maybe some other code now?

I am tempted to just go with [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), but 1) I am not sure if it will port to every embedded processor I might want to use and 2) on their website, they say that they doesn't guarantee/recommend certain parts of it for embedded systems (especially FSMs, which seems weird). If I go for Boost & we find a problem later ....

Comment: STL is part of the C++ language If you're worried about memory, replace operator new and delete with your own memory management.

Comment: Have you checked the uSTL? http://ustl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Looks good, thanks. I need to delve deeper into portability, of course.

Comment: Most of the C++ containers take an "allocator" object, that tells it where to get dynamic memory.  You can have complete control over the memory, quite easily.  (not everything takes allocators, but most things do)

Comment: Have a look at Meyer's slides about using C++ for embedded: http://htrd.su/wiki/_media/zhurnal/2013/03/28/scott_meyers._effective_c_in_an_embedded_environment/effectcppemb.pdf

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Super-safe & lose much of what
>   constitutes C++ (imo, it's more than
>   just the language definition) and
>   maybe run into problems later or have
>   to add lots of exception handling &
>   maybe some other code now?

We have a similar debate in the game world and people come down on both sides.  Regarding the quoted part, why would you be concerned about losing "much of what constitutes C++"?  If it's not pragmatic, don't use it.  It shouldn't matter if it's "C++" or not.

Run some tests.  Can you get around STL's memory management in ways that satisfy you?  If so, was it worth the effort?  A lot of problems STL and boost are designed to solve just plain don't come up if you design to avoid haphazard dynamic memory allocation... does STL solve a specific problem you face?

Lots of people have tackled STL in tight environments and been happy with it.  Lots of people just avoid it.  Some people propose [entirely new standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html).  I don't think there's one right answer.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, this and others (also voted up) made me actually think.  Since we have an embedded system, we have our own memory pool. STL is useful to us mostly for container classes; but we max them at initialization time. So, either we live with that & rule no STL allocation after system start-up, or we can just use plain old arrays (of pointers to statically allocated objects)

Answer (score 61):

I work on real-time embedded systems every day. Of course, my definition of embedded system may be different than yours. But we make full use of the STL and exceptions and do not experience any unmanageable problems. We also make use of dynamic memory (at a very high rate; allocating lots of packets per second, etc.) and have not yet needed to resort to any custom allocators or memory pools. We have even used C++ in interrupt handlers. We don't use boost, but only because a certain government agency won't let us.

It is our experience you can indeed use many modern C++ features in an embedded environment as long as you use your head and conduct your own benchmarks. I highly recommend you make use of Scott Meyer's *Effective C++* 3rd edition as well as Sutter and Alexandrescu's *C++ Coding Standards* to assist you in using C++ with a sane programming style.

Edit: After getting an upvote on this 2 years later, let me post an update. We are much farther along in our development and we have finally hit spots in our code where the standard library containers are too slow under high performance conditions. Here we did in fact resort to custom algorithms, memory pools, and simplified containers. That is the beauty of C++ though, you can use the standard library and get all the good things it provides for 90% of your use cases. You don't throw it all out when you meet problems, you just hand-optimize the trouble spots.

Comment: +1, useful answer. But I don't think you know as much about exceptions or code bloat as you think you do -- please see my comments in response to yours on others' posts.

Comment: Where exactly in my response does the phrase "code bloat" appear? I appreciate the +1 but please direct your comments to this particular answer.

Comment: sounds great (and, yes, both of those books (and the complete Meyers "effective...") are sitting beside my monitor right now.   

What sort of processors do you target?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Boost yet?

Answer (score 28):

The other posts have addressed the important issues of dynamic memory allocation, exceptions and possible code bloat.  I just want to add: Don't forget about `<algorithm>`!  Regardless of whether you use STL vectors or plain C arrays and pointers, you can still use `sort()`, `binary_search()`, `random_shuffle()`, the functions for building and managing heaps, etc.  These routines will almost certainly be faster and less buggy than versions you build yourself.

Example: unless you think about it carefully, a shuffle algorithm you build yourself [is likely to produce skewed distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859253/why-does-this-simple-shuffle-algorithm-produce-biased-results-what-is-a-simple); `random_shuffle()` won't.

Answer (score 20):

Paul Pedriana from Electronic Arts wrote in 2007 [a lengthy treatise](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) on why the STL was inappropriate for embedded console development and why they had to write their own. It's a detailed article, but the most important reasons were:

1. STL allocators are slow, bloated,
   and inefficient
2. Compilers aren't actually very good at inlining all those deep function calls
3. STL allocators don't support explicit alignment
4. The STL algorithms that come with GCC and MSVC's STL aren't very performant, because they're very platform-agnostic and thus miss a lot of microoptimizations that can make a big difference.

Some years ago, our company made the decision not to use the STL at all, instead implementing our own system of containers that are maximally performant, easier to debug, and more conservative of memory. It was a lot of work but it has repaid itself many times over. But ours is a space in which products compete on how much they can cram into 16.6ms with a given CPU and memory size.

As to exceptions: [they are slow](http://www.gamearchitect.net/Articles/ExceptionsAndErrorCodes.html) on consoles, and anyone who tells you otherwise hasn't tried timing them. Simply compiling with them enabled will slow down the entire program because of the necessary prolog/epilog code -- measure it yourself if you don't believe me. It's even worse on in-order CPUs than it is on the x86. For this reason, the compiler we use doesn't even support C++ exceptions.

The performance gain isn't so much from avoiding the cost of an exception throw — it's from disabling exceptions entirely.

Comment: You've linked an article from 2006 which is now out of date. C++ exceptions aren't slow on decent modern compilers. If you're dealing with an embedded system for which a decent modern copmiler doesn't exist you have a problem - but to give a blanket "As to exceptions: they are slow" is flat out wrong.

Comment: Recognized C++ experts like Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu disagree with your "exceptions are slow" statement. If you don't use exceptions, you yourself are now responsible for writing and checking error return codes, and this code is almost always less efficient and compared to the code modern compilers emit for exceptions. Furthermore, the code people write (if they bother to write it at all) to check error codes is often rife with errors and mistakes.

Comment: It hasn't been our experience that STL allocators are slow, bloated, or inefficient. In fact, its often better to use them than something that you wrote yourself, since millions of people have used them and the bugs are shaken out of them. As for your #3, you can supply your own allocator that meets your alignment requirements to just about anything in the STL. And I simply don't believe #4. I've seen the GCC STL make platform specific optimizations. Also, did you know std::copy() turns into a std::memcpy() if it detects it is using native types on GCC?

Comment: Exceptions are not very slow, but they do impose a nonzero runtime overhead on at least one popular modern compiler (MSVC++9) even when no exception is ever thrown.  To see this, try compiling (not linking) http://pastebin.com/m1fb29a45 with `/EHa` and then with `/EHsc`, using /Fa to produce an assembly listing.  In both cases, Win32 structured exception handling (SEH) management is introduced  -- that's the additional pushing of data onto the stack and setting of the `FS` segment register.

Comment: The article is from 2006, but *my own* timings were from August 2009.  I have read all the theory about how exceptions aren't slow any more **but they do not corroborate with actual measurements I have taken**.

Comment: Brian: those are EA's points, not mine, but #4 was determined empirically. Basically, they wrote their own implementations of the containers, and found that they ran much faster than the STL's. Therefore, the STL is not maximally efficient.

Comment: Recognized experts like data when profiling disagree with 'red book blind reading is always right' statement.

Answer (score 16):

Let me start out by saying I haven't done embedded work for a few years, and never in C++, so my advice is worth every penny you're paying for it...

The templates utilized by STL are never going to generate code you wouldn't need to generate yourself, so I wouldn't worry about code bloat.

The STL doesn't throw exceptions on its own, so that shouldn't be a concern.  If your classes don't throw, you should be safe.  Divide your object initialization into two parts, let the constructor create a bare bones object and then do any initialization that could fail in a member function that returns an error code.

I think all of the container classes will let you define your own allocation function, so if you want to allocate from a pool you can make it happen.

Comment: +1, I think this is one of the few times it's a good idea to move construction work out of constructors.

Comment: What do you mean "the STL doesn't throw exceptions on its own"? What if you call vector::at with an out of range index? And you can also configure IO streams to throw exceptions.

Also, templates can generate more code than you may if you wrote it by hand. See the example in Stroustrup about combining a template with void* to reduce such bloat.

Comment: @Brian: `vector::at()` is a good example. It would be more accurate to say that the STL can be used in such a way that it will never generate exceptions (here, by using `operator[]()` instead of `at()`) and without making any additional compromises.

Comment: @Brian: Regarding code bloat, functions comprising identical object code will be removed at link time with MSVC++ if you specify /Gy to the compiler and /OPT:ICF to the linker.  I believe the GNU linker can do much the same.

Comment: @Brian Neal, I forgot about `vector::at`, and probably a few others too - thanks for the clarification. It should be possible to search your standard library files for "throw" and find all of the 'exceptions' to my overly generalized statement.

Comment: @j_random_hacker We don't often get to use MSVC++ in embedded systems. GNU is much more common, but there are many more crappy compilers in the embedded systems world than in the desktop world.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - In general I agree with you that you can tip-toe around exceptions in the STL and standard library. However, exceptions are the normal way that the standard library and STL report errors. In general, it is not a good idea to shut your compiler's exception handling off unless you have a really good reason, otherwise the standard library won't report errors correctly. This is even if you choose to not use exceptions in your own code. More interesting discussion on this can be found in item 72 in Sutter & Alexandrescu's C++ Coding Standards.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I use templates all the time and we don't see excessive problems with template code bloat in our embedded work. However my comment, if you bothered to read it, said that you can *sometimes* generate less code than templates if you wrote it by hand. Again, see Stroustrup's example of how he combines a type-unsafe void* algorithm with a type-safe thin template versus having 2 separate and complete template instantiations on different types. That's all I was trying to say.

Comment: @Brian: I read your comment, no need to repeat it or say "if you bothered to read it". You provided some useful info, and so did I. Right?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Well you implied in your response to my answer that you didn't agree with some comment I made about code bloat. Since this is the only place were I mentioned that, I felt I had to add more information. In any event I think you missed the original point I was trying and failing to make. But who cares.

Answer (score 12):

The open source project ["Embedded Template Library (ETL)"](http://www.etlcpp.com) targets the usual problems with the STL used in Embedded Applications by providing/implementing a library:

- deterministic behaviour
- "Create a set of containers where the size or maximum size is determined at compile time. These containers should be largely equivalent to those supplied in the STL, with a compatible API."
- no dynamic memory allocation
- no RTTI required
- little use of virtual functions (only when absolutely necessary)
- set of fixed capacity containers
- cache friendly storage of containers as continously allocated memory block
- reduced container code size
- typesafe smart enumerations
- CRC calculations
- checksums & hash functions
- variants = sort of type safe unions
- Choice of asserts, exceptions, error handler or no checks on errors
- heavily unit tested
- well documented source code
- and other features...

You can also consider a commercial [C++ STL for Embedded Developers](https://www.esrlabs.com/blog/estl-for-embedded-developers) provided by E.S.R. Labs.

Answer (score 5):

1. for memory management, you can implement your own allocator, which request memory from the pool. And all STL container have a template for the allocator.
2. for exception, STL doesn't throw many exceptions, in generally, the most common are: out of memory, in your case, the system should reset, so you can do reset in the allocator. others are such as out of range, you can avoid it by the user.
3. so, i think you can use STL in embedded system :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all comments, I would propose you reading of [Technical Report on C++ Performance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf) which specifically addresses topics that you are interested in: using C++ in embedded (including hard real-time systems); how exception-handling usually implemented and which overhead it has; free store allocation's overhead.

The report is really good as is debunks many popular tails about C++ performance.

Answer (score 3):

It basically depends on your compiler and in the amount of memory you have. If you have more than a few Kb of ram, having dynamic memory allocation helps a lot. If the implementation of malloc from the standard library that you have is not tuned to your memory size you can write your own, or there are nice examples around such as [mm_malloc from Ralph Hempel](http://www.hempeldesigngroup.com/embedded/stories/memoryManager.html) that you can use to write your new and delete operators on top.

I don't agree with those that repeat the meme that exceptions and stl containers are too slow, or too bloated etc. Of course it adds a little more code than a simple C's malloc, but judicious use of exceptions can make code much clear and avoid too much error checking blurb in C.

One has to keep in mind that STL allocators will increase their allocations in powers of two, which means sometimes it will do some reallocations until it reaches the correct size, which you can prevent with **reserve** so it becomes as cheap as one malloc of the desired size if you know the size to allocate anyway.

If you have a big buffer in a vector for example, at some point it might do a reallocation and ends using up 1.5x the memory size that you are intending it to use at some point while reallocating and moving data. (For example, at some point it has N bytes allocated, you add data via append or an insertion iterator and it allocates 2N bytes, copies the first N and releases N. You have 3N bytes allocated at some point).

So in the end it has a lot of advantages, and pays of if you know what you are doing. You should know a little of how C++ works to use it on embedded projects without surprises.

And to the guy of the fixed buffers and reset, you can always reset inside the new operator or whatever if you are out of memory, but that would mean you did a bad design that can exhaust your memory.

An exception being thrown with ARM realview 3.1:

```
--- OSD\#1504 throw fapi_error("OSDHANDLER_BitBlitFill",res);
   S:218E72F0 E1A00000  MOV      r0,r0
   S:218E72F4 E58D0004  STR      r0,[sp,#4]
   S:218E72F8 E1A02000  MOV      r2,r0
   S:218E72FC E24F109C  ADR      r1,{pc}-0x94 ; 0x218e7268
   S:218E7300 E28D0010  ADD      r0,sp,#0x10
   S:218E7304 FA0621E3  BLX      _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE       <0x21a6fa98>
   S:218E7308 E1A0B000  MOV      r11,r0
   S:218E730C E1A0200A  MOV      r2,r10
   S:218E7310 E1A01000  MOV      r1,r0
   S:218E7314 E28D0014  ADD      r0,sp,#0x14
   S:218E7318 EB05C35F  BL       fapi_error::fapi_error   <0x21a5809c>
   S:218E731C E3A00008  MOV      r0,#8
   S:218E7320 FA056C58  BLX      __cxa_allocate_exception <0x21a42488>
   S:218E7324 E58D0008  STR      r0,[sp,#8]
   S:218E7328 E28D1014  ADD      r1,sp,#0x14
   S:218E732C EB05C340  BL       _ZN10fapi_errorC1ERKS_   <0x21a58034>
   S:218E7330 E58D0008  STR      r0,[sp,#8]
   S:218E7334 E28D0014  ADD      r0,sp,#0x14
   S:218E7338 EB05C36E  BL       _ZN10fapi_errorD1Ev      <0x21a580f8>
   S:218E733C E51F2F98  LDR      r2,0x218e63ac            <OSD\#1126>
   S:218E7340 E51F1F98  LDR      r1,0x218e63b0            <OSD\#1126>
   S:218E7344 E59D0008  LDR      r0,[sp,#8]
   S:218E7348 FB056D05  BLX      __cxa_throw              <0x21a42766>
```

Doesn't seem so scary, and no overhead is added inside {} blocks or functions if the exception isn't thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some [benefits of C++ over C for embedded environments](https://youtu.be/QwDUJYLCpxo). You do not always need exception handling or RTTI or dynamic memroy management for using C++. You have the compiler options to turn them off. Not all STL containers us dynamicemory and very few - other than iostream - use RTTI. Most of the functions are marked `noexcept`; meaning they don't expect exceptions.
The major avantage of C++ over C is that the former is pushing everything toward compile-time, while the later is trying to achieve polymorphism at run-time. Compile-time workload means early failure detection preventing production catastrophy. C lacks the abstraction mechanisms necessary for compile-time computation; Nor does it provide enough facilities for ensuring type safety and security. The only reason for C not being totally replace with C++ in all codebases is mental inertia (includes Linus Torvalds' C++phobia). If - instead of providing C++ bindings for C libraries - C++ communities had tried the reverse, the benefits would've been vivid by now. C++ community should provide 1st hand rewrite of important libraries, along with C bindings for backwards compatibility to showcase the real beastfull potentials of C++.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with STL in embedded systems is the memory allocation issue (which, as you said, causes a lot of problems).

I'd seriously research creating your own memory management, built by overriding the new/delete operators. I'm pretty sure that with a bit of time, it can be done, and it's almost certainly worth it.

As for the exceptions issue, I wouldn't go there. Exceptions are a **serious slowdown** of your code, because they cause every single block (`{ }`) to have code before and after, allowing the catching of the exception and the destruction of any objects contained within. I don't have hard data on this on hand, but every time I've seen this issue come up, I've seen overwhelming evidence of a massive slowdown caused by using exceptions.

**Edit:**
Since a lot of people wrote comments stating that exception handling is **not** slower, I thought I'd add this little note (thanks for the people who wrote this in comments, I thought it'd be good to add it here).

The reason exception handling slows down your code is because the compiler must make sure that every block (`{}`), from the place an exception is thrown to the place it is dealt with, must deallocate any objects within it. This is code that is added to every block, regardless of whether anyone ever throws an exception or not (since the compiler can't tell at compile time whether this block will be part of an exception "chain").

Of course, this might be an old way of doing things that has gotten much faster in newer compilers (I'm not exactly up-to-date on C++ compiler optimizations). The best way to know is just to run some sample code, with exceptions turned on and off (and which includes a few nested functions), and time the difference.

Comment: -1 for complete lack of understanding of how exceptions are implemented.

Comment: Exceptions, when implemented by modern compilers, typically do not cause run time overhead unless an exception is actually thrown. And if you use exceptions carefully (and not for normal flow control) performance will not be an issue when things are going wrong.

Comment: Have you timed that, Brian? The last time I tried measuring it (last summer), I found that simply enabling exceptions and stack unwinding in compiler settings caused a slowdown, regardless of whether I actually threw any exceptions or not.

Comment: @Brian: At least on Win32, every `try` block must set up an `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` block on the stack and point the FS register at it. This happens regardless of whether any exceptions actually occur. Source: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx  Also the compiler *must* add code to every block that declares any objects with non-trivial destructors, unless it can prove that an exception cannot occur inside the block. Otherwise, how will those objects be destroyed during stack unwinding?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You're talking about Win32 structured exceptions, not C++ exceptions. The two concepts are totally seperate. As for the stack unwinding- that happens when a function exits, regardless of whether it exits via an exception or a return statement.

Comment: @Edan Maor/Crashworks: Please be specific about what compiler you're using and what version. Up to date versions of the better compilers use zero-overhead exception handling.

Comment: @Joe: MSVC++ uses Win32 SEH for C++ exceptions, you can catch a SEH exception in C++ using `catch (...)`.  See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de5awhsw%28VS.71%29.aspx Other compilers may do differently of course, but SEH has special support from the OS and so is likely to be more efficient than alternatives.

Comment: @Joe: You seem to forget that stack unwinding needs to know which objects with non-trivial dtors need to have their dtors called. Consider this func: `void f() { X a; { X b; i_throw(); X c; } other_code(); X d; }`. `X` has a non-trivial dtor. Now `a` and `b` must be destroyed, without `other_code()` being run or `d` being constructed. To do this with no additional setup overhead would mean `JMP`-ing to a pre-existing address that performs this sequence of steps -- but because of `other_code()`, no such sequence exists. Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: @Joe: Like I said, I'm no expert in this field (I haven't done embedded C++ in a while now), I just think the OP should **their** compiler, to see if it involves overhead or not. Since a lot of compilers **do** involve overhead, it's worth checking out.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Your information on MSVC using SEH for C++ exceptions is years out of date - MSVC 7.1 acts like that by default, VC8, VC9 and VC10 can be made to act like that with a compiler switch, but by default they don't. SEH is much slower than C++ exceptions because the compiler must generate code as if every statement could throw an exception.

Comment: @ j_random_hacker: re. stackunwinding - You're comparing code which handles errors using exceptions to code that doesn't handle errors. If you replaced the call to `i_throw();` with an `if( i_return_error_code() == ERROR){return;}` the compiler would have to generate exactly the same stack unwinding code.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - So you are telling me that stack doesn't unwind and objects are not destroyed when you turn off exceptions? You aren't making any sense. That kind of behavior must occur regardless of exceptions being off or on, as Joe Gauterin points out.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, stack unwinding must happen in any case. But, afaik, if exceptions are enabled, then an exception thrown somewhere 5 blocks in (a function calling a function, etc.), must now walk backwards through all 5 functions, and call the dtors in those functions. This needs code surrounding each function, and this code does NOT need to exist if exception handling isn't enabled (since the dtor will only be called at the end of the block, period). Am I making any sense?

Comment: Also, obviously code that doesn't use exceptions will use some different method (error codes) with overhead. However, I'm talking about the overhead that *some* compilers will put in automatically, around every block, which I think still constitutes a slowdown.

Comment: One last thing, this subject has a lot of questions already devoted to it on SO, which I think are a better place to discuss it. I'd like to direct your attention to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691168/how-much-footprint-does-c-exception-handling-add

Comment: @Edan Maor: Certainly the compiler must generate more code to handle these cases when exceptions are turned on. That is unavoidable. However this code need not add any time overhead if no exception occurs. This extra code will not be executed in the "normal" case when exceptions are not thrown. This is why it is important to only use exceptions for violations of preconditions or other invariants and not "normal" flow control.

Comment: @Edan Maor: And the next step is to compare this extra code to the amount of hand written code that must be developed to check and set return codes when you can't do exceptions, and weigh the costs in that light. Most people, if they even bother to check return codes, don't do such a great job at it, and this code is error prone and leaky.

Comment: @Joe: Re stackunwinding: I see what you mean, since if you don't use exceptions then you should check every function's return code for errors. But many real-world functions *cannot fail*, and turning on any form of exception handling will force this overhead to occur whenever you have a block scope containing both an object with non-trivial dtor and a call to a C++ function from another translation unit (because then the compiler can't prove no C++ exceptions can take place). `/EHsc` will exempt `extern C` calls, but not calls to C++ functions.

Comment: @Joe: You claim that my statement about SEH is out of date, so you haven't checked the assembly generated under the various options.  Regardless of whether you specify `/EHa` (the "old" way that specifically handles SEH exceptions) or `/EHsc` ("only C++ exceptions"), if you have an object with non-triv dtor occurring in the same block as a call to an external function then instructions to populate a `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` struct and set `FS` are generated. SEH is used either way. Compile (don't link) http://pastebin.com/m1fb29a45 with /Fa + /EH, /EHsc and /EHa to convince yourself.

Comment: @Brian: Of course objects are destroyed and dtors called on normal scope exit.  But if exceptions are being used, then only a subset of dtors are called, and there is no other program code being run in-between.  That means that in general, stack unwinding due to a `throw` can't simply `JMP` to some place in the pre-existing, normal-scope-exit code to perform cleanup -- instead it needs to somehow keep track of which objects require dtors to be run at any point.  I.e. additional overhead is required.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, sure but my point was that this overhead is just extra code; a good compiler will not cause any runtime impact unless an exception actually occurs.

Comment: Brian, have you actually tried it -- comparing a build with exceptions totally disabled to one with exceptions?  If so, and it's the same, which compiler?

Comment: @Crashworks, compare what? Code size or execution time?. Yes, you do get more code when you have exceptions turned on. This is unavoidable and to be expected. Maybe that is the deal breaker for you. However, in my experience, on a good compiler (and I'm not talking about MSVC++) this extra code doesn't actually execute until an exception is thrown. The compilers we use are GCC and Green Hills MULTI. The compilers are not perfect, it isn't true 0% overhead until an exception is thrown, but the results of doing this are acceptable for our application.

Comment: @Brian: For the record, I wasn't talking about code size, I was talking about execution time. From the results I've seen (on older compilers), execution time *is* longer, even if no exceptions are thrown. Just turning them on will cause a significant slowdown.

Comment: @Brian: Interestingly, I just tried a variation of my pastebin snippet on Linux x86 g++ 4.2.1 and to its credit, the only difference was an extra 32 bytes allocated on the stack -- but not written to. So it seems that in a function, if there are any local variables that don't fit in registers (meaning space has to be allocated on the stack anyway), *no additional instructions will be executed if no exceptions are caught or thrown*. Very impressive!

Answer (score 1):

On our embedded scanner project we were developing a board with ARM7 CPU and STL didn't bring any issue. Surely the project details are important since dynamic memory allocation may not be an issue for many available boards today and type of projects.

Comment: +1 a good point. The processors in "embedded" projects are becoming more powerful. My current Atmel processor is a UC3 series, which is 32 bit. When I started out, embedded meant 4 or 8 bits. However, the 32 bit processor has only 512kB user memory, which makes things a bit tight. You don't have any memory issues?