# Does BREW 3.1.5 support STL?

Tags: c++, brew-framework, brewmp

I'm creating an application in BREW, by using C++. Does 3.1.5 sdk version support STL?

Comment: Random developer claims to use STL: https://developer.brewmp.com/forum/brew-c

Comment: https://developer.brewmp.com/forum/seeking-official-definitive-situation-regarding-brew-mp-and-c Look for: "There are large sections of the STL that would need serious rethinking to ever work on the BREW platform ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BREW platform does not support exceptions, also it has no stream based I/O. This could explain why [some](https://developer.brewmp.com/forum/brew-c) have reported success using STL, while others shun it. As long as you stay away from the parts of STL that is problematic on BREW, it might work, but it's far from fool proof. Personally, I would avoid it.

If you are going to use it, a mandatory requirement is to overload new/delete with BREW's MALLOC() and FREE().

Also related reading:

- [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html)
- [to use STL or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226252/embedded-c-to-use-stl-or-not)