# Vector header file in AVR-Studio

Tags: c++, header-files, avr, avr-studio6

I have a compression algorithm that uses some c++ functions and I would like to try it on AVR sS
vector: No such file or directory

I use vectors in my algorithm so I must include the vector

```
#include <vector>
```

What I want to ask is that, does atmel AVR Studio provide me with all the libraries a normal gcc compiler does? (Is there a support for vectors in AVR Studio?)

BTW I am using AVR studio 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While most people think that C++ is quite overkill for small 8 bits MCU, you can still use C++ with these devices. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226252/embedded-c-to-use-stl-or-not).

AFAIK, there is no native support for the standard C++ library in AVR Studio 6, even partial support.

However, there are some *STL* ports available on the internet. 
I used some time ago [this one](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/), with some difficulties for compilation. It provides a quite complete support of basic containers (I used `vector` and `map`). Do not expect to have much more.

As a side note, I never managed to be completely satisfied with the result: too much memory consumption for not so much gain. I ended in using C on small projects and used bigger 32 bits MCU for my larger projects.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. You have guided me to much new information.