# Cost of Exception Handling on Embedded Systems

Tags: c++, exception, esp8266

I'm writing C++ and running on an ESP8266. I'm working with the open-source [ESP8266WebServer FSBrowser](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples) example. In this code ([sample](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser/FSBrowser.ino#L312-L332)), the error handling strategy consists of sending an HTTP error code and then returning, referred to as [guard clauses](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-01/guard-clauses/). It looks something like this:

```
void handleDirectoryList() {
  if (!fsOK) {
    api->sendServerError(FS_INIT_ERROR);
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

I'd like to replace the `return` statements with exceptions, since this leads to cleaner code. For example, I cannot extract these error handling methods because of the `return`, whereas with exceptions, I can extract method and reuse.

Are there any *practical* reasons why I should avoid exceptions on an embedded system, such as the ESP8266?

**EDIT:** How can the performance and memory cost of exception handling vs. return codes be quantified on a specific embedded platform in order to make a calculated decision?

Comment: Does it work? Does it cause *measurable* performance problems? Are you popping enough of these that it matters?

Comment: @tadman The error checking happens when the HTTP endpoints are called and there is an error in the request, which is not that often, on the order of seconds or minutes. Just to be clear, you're suggesting to just use exceptions (without understanding side-effects or best practices) and if there's no visible issue, don't worry about it, right?

Comment: Exceptions come with a bit of overhead, but it's usually modest unless you're really abusing them, like using exceptions to transport data or something really *wrong*. As with anything embedded you'll want to fuzz the heck out of this to be sure it doesn't choke or lock up, but that's the same no matter what strategy you use, so you can be confident they do work if you test thoroughly enough.

Comment: Exceptions are just a flow-control mechanism, so if they're supported and you're not using them too aggressively you should be fine. That being said, test, test, test, test and test some more to be sure they work in your code. That chip has limited stack space, so it's reasonable to be cautious, but it can't be that bad.

Comment: There are reasons, of course, but only you may know whether they apply to your code. Exceptions could mean increased code size. Exceptions require RTTI, which also require some additional memory space. On the positive side, exceptions usually cost very little or nothing at all in execution speed when they are not thrown.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., I understand that there will be a processing and memory overhead, but how can I quantify this? If we're talking about 0.1% difference (hypothetically), then I'd be willing pay that for cleaner code. Obviously, the impact depends on the application and system specs, so there must be a cross-over point where the exception handling overhead becomes negligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedded C++ : to use exceptions or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226227/embedded-c-to-use-exceptions-or-not)